# How to trim to first "/" in php string

Tags: php, trim

I have a string in php that is simply a file path, ie "images/steven/pic.jpg"

The php script displays a list of the pics in all of images' subfolders, so the end result is something like this:

```
"images/steven/pic1.jpg"
"images/steven/pic2.jpg"
"images/steven/pic3.jpg"
"images/betty/pic1.jpg"
"images/betty/pic2.jpg"
"images/craig/pic1.jpg"
"images/craig/pic2.jpg"
```

Its really not necessary to have `"images/"` on each string and it takes up a lot of space, how would i trim off just that part of the string so it outputs `"steven/pic1.jpg"` etc?

The strings are in an array that i echo via foreach, so i'd like simply attach the trim function to "" to keep it neat.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
$str = "images/steven/pic1.jpg";
echo substr( $str, strpos( $str, '/') + 1);
```

This will output: `"steven/pic1.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

If it always is `images/` then simply do:

```
str_replace("images/", "", $yourstring);
```

Comment: Attention: str_replace() replaces everywhere in the string. That is an unnecessary risk.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_replace('#^[^/]*/#', '', 'images/craig/pic2.jpg');
```